# EPStatmentObject model not working?

Tags: esper

Im trying to modify an epl  by compiling it using the compileEPL() method and add more to e.g the where clause, however im havin trouble getting it work.

Lets say this is my epl:

```
select * from event where A = 1
```

and I want to add another where condition using the AND

and I compile the epl using compileEPL()

```
model.getWhereClause().getChildren().add(Expressions.and()
                        .add(Expressions.eq("B", )));
```

instead of giving me:

```
select * from event where A = 1 and B = 2 it just gives ..where A = 1 and not adding the new where clause.
```

Am I doing it wrong? The EPStatementObjectModel works fine for building an object EPL from scratch but not when compiling it and adding or modify it.

Does anyone know? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where-clause is rooted in an EQ since "A=1".

```
Expression equalsExpr = model.getWhereClause();
```

So construct an AND clause that holds the old EQ and the new EQ.

```
Expression and = Expressions.and().add(equalsExpr).add(Expressions.eq("B", ...));
```

Finally set the "and" as the new where-clause:

```
model.setWhereClause(and);
```

In summary, when modifying expressions to add "and": when old expression is not itself an AND you should build an AND node and add the old expression and new ones.

Comment: thanks! This worked. Is it the same approach for the other clauses like select properties and from properties as well? I will try now in the meantime.

Comment: How about contexts?  That was even more confusing. The documentation dosent say how to create one using the EPStmtObj. But for context using crontabs it probaly easier to just create it manually with string variables?

Comment: one more thing. When i try to getWhereClause and print it as a string it dosent show the values just a path to the client.soda package

Comment: The same approach for the other places where expressions occur.

Comment: I take an EPL, compile it to model, and use the IDE debugger and inspect the object graph in the debugger. This way I can see how any EPL object graph looks. For contexts there is CreateContextClause on the model.

Comment: Call "expression.toEPL(writer, ExpressionPrecedenceEnum.MINIMUM)" for to-string of expression.

Comment: Did you use a plugin to get the object graph? or does esper have a debug tool?